# The kernel of $C^{*}(G)\to C_{r}^{*}(G)$

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be  a  locally compact group. Put $I(G)=\ker: C^{*}(G) \to C_{r}^{*} (G)$, the kernel of the canonical morphism.

What type of  $C^{*}$ algebras can not be isomorphic to $I(G)$, for  some locally  compact group $G$?In particular finit  dimensional, unital, abelian,. etc? Is there any reference for characterization of  such algebras?

Comment: This is a wide open question. I personally believe that, for $G$ discrete, the question is intractable, because a description of $I(G)$ is very much related to a description of the dual $\hat{G}$. As an example, consider a residually finite group with property (T). It is known that each finite-dimensional rep is isolated in $\hat{G}$, so defines a direct summand of $C^*(G)$ isomorphic to a matrix algebra. So $I(G)$ contains a huge direct sum of matrix algebras, and probably lots of other stuff too.

Comment: @AlainValette Prof. Valette, Thank you very much for your very interesting comment.

Comment: @AlainValette  Can I ask you to give a reference for these materials?

Comment: @AlainValette  I apologize for this second message. may you give a reference on material of your comment. thank you.

Comment: See "On Isolated Points in the Dual Spaces of Locally Compact Groups", by S. P. Wang, Mathematische Annalen (1975)
Volume: 218, page 19-34; available on http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002311909&IDDOC=125326